# How to change deserialized type at runtime using JSON.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I'm trying to add some properties to a model arriving from an external assembly (can NOT be modified). So, I get the model, it is serialized as JSON, then deserialized as dynamic object (ExpandoObject), new properties are added, the dynamic object is serialized to JSON; but when I try to deserialize, as everybody should expect the contained type is deserialized with the original type (A class in the example) and not as the extended (ExtendedA in the example). See the following code:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    private static object ConvertJTokenToObject(JToken token)
    {
        if (token is JValue)
        {
            return ((JValue)token).Value;
        }
        if (token is JObject)
        {
            var expando = new ExpandoObject();
            (from childToken in ((JToken)token) where childToken is JProperty select childToken as JProperty).ToList().ForEach(property =>
            {
                ((IDictionary<string, object>)expando).Add(property.Name, ConvertJTokenToObject(property.Value));
            });
            return expando;
        }
        if (token is JArray)
        {
            object[] array = new object[((JArray)token).Count];
            int index = 0;
            foreach (JToken arrayItem in ((JArray)token))
            {
                array[index] = ConvertJTokenToObject(arrayItem);
                index++;
            }
            return array;
        }
        throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Unknown token type '{0}'", token.GetType()), "token");
    }

    public static ExpandoObject ToExpando(this string json)
    {
        JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(json);
        dynamic dynObject = ConvertJTokenToObject(jsonObject);
        return (ExpandoObject)dynObject;
    }
}

public class A //Defined in an external assembly
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
}

public class B //Defined in an external assembly
{
    public List<A> Properties { get; set; }
}

public class ExtendedA : A
{
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myObject = new B() //This is an example but in real code this object arrive from an external module that can't be modified, something like: B myObject = ExternalAssembly.GetB();
        {
            Properties = new List<A>()
            {
                new A() { Property1 = "value 1" },
                new A() { Property1 = "value 2" },
                new A() { Property1 = "value 3" }
            }
        };
        string jsonObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject);
        dynamic expandoObject = jsonObject.ToExpando();
        for (int index = 0; index < expandoObject.Properties.Length; index++)
        {
            expandoObject.Properties[index].Property2 = Guid.NewGuid();
        }
        jsonObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(expandoObject);
        B myExtendedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<B>(jsonObject);
    }
}
```

How I can deserialize the "new created type" in a way that use class ExtendedA instead class A? There is a way to specify the mapper in the deserialization call? Any suggestion?